# ASP.Net Core SignalR not working with Xamarin iOS client

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, asp.net-core-signalr

Based on the info here https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/305 I was hoping to get my iOS client working with ASP.Net Core SignalR, but still no luck. I get an exception when the client tries to connect to the hub:

```
//  Connect to the SignalR hub.
string url = 
$"http://{DataService.HostName}:{DataService.MainPort.ToString()}/hub";
try
{
    MediaHubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(url).Build();
}
catch (Exception e)
{ // Handle exception }
```

The code above works fine in the iDevice simulator, but crashes on the device itself. I am using Visual Studio 15.8.0 with Xamarin iOS 11.14.0.13 on Windows 10, and on the Mac Visual Studio for Mac 7.6.1 Build 9 with Xamarin iOS 11.14.0.13 there as well. And the latest released Nugets for AspNetCore SignalR (server and client).

Anyone else run into this behavior? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the *exact* exception(s)?

Comment: Here it is: A suitable constructor for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HttpConnectionFactory could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

Comment: ask this on [github in the question topic](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1886)

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the link, I will post this question there as well.

Comment: After some more investigation and testing, with assistance from the team at Microsoft, it appears that the root cause has been found. See [link](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2933) for details and a potental workaround (it solved my issue).